# Textbox binding to object breaks binding (type)

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, binding

In my Application I have a problem which I simulated with a little demo application.

I have a ViewModel for a ListBoxItem which has a Value Property of Type `object`. This can be Int32, Decimal, String ...

When I load the Value and get it without edit it stays the same `Type`

[image]

When I append a 4 into the textbox and get the value

[image]

The Property becomes a `String`.

Why is my `TextBox` binding changing the type of my bound object when I edit the value?

**edit:**
This is the Property:

```
public int TestProperty
        {
            get { return _testProperty; }
            set
            {
                if (Equals(value, _testProperty)) return;
                _testProperty = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
```

And I assign Int32 Value `123` to it:

```
TestProperty = 123;
```

Before and after typing into the textbox I call this line:

```
 StatusMessage = string.Format("Current Type: {0} Value: {1}", _testProperty.GetType().Name, _testProperty);
```

**edit 2:**
It works with this (Setting `x:Shared` to false):

```
 public class PreserveTypeValueConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public Type Type { get; private set; }

        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            try
            {
                Type = value.GetType();
                return System.Convert.ChangeType(value, targetType, culture);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                return new ValidationResult(false, string.Format("Cannot convert {0} to {1}", value.GetType().Name, targetType.Name));
            }
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            try
            {
                return System.Convert.ChangeType(value, Type, culture);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                return new ValidationResult(false, string.Format("Cannot convert {0} to {1}", value.GetType().Name, targetType.Name));
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Could you show the test code, specifically the xaml?

Answer (score 1):

The .NET Framework will convert your `int` to a `string` to display in the `TextBox`. I can only imagine that your *actual* property type is `object`, so the Framework wouldn't know what type (eg. `int`) to convert it back to from the `string`. It would work if you used a strongly typed property, eg. of type `int`.

Answer (score 1):

You input text data. If your datasource implemented like int, TextBox has default settings to apply ValidationError and use default converter for default types. But for unknown types, which have not CLR metadata, it simply calls .ToString() when you Convert/ConvertBack value from TextBox to your property or visa versa.
If you want, you can write your own converter IValueConverter.

Comment: I think the BindingExpression will determine the type based on the Compiled Type and not by runtime. So it could be that when Binding updates the source it finds an object and not the runtime type Int32.